# x3d texture filtering mode

Tags: x3d, x3dom

Looking at [ImageTexture](http://doc.x3dom.org/developer/x3dom/nodeTypes/ImageTexture.html) and [TextureProperties](http://doc.x3dom.org/developer/x3dom/nodeTypes/TextureProperties.html), it's unclear to me how to set up properties.
How to specify magnificationFilter & minificationFilter to be linear?

```
<transform scale="1.01 1.01 1.01">
    <shape>
        <sphere></sphere>
        <appearance>
            <ImageTexture url="texture.png"></ImageTexture>
        </appearance>
    </shape>
</transform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ImageTexture url="texture.png">
    <TextureProperties generateMipMaps='TRUE' minificationFilter='LINEAR' magnificationFilter='LINEAR'></TextureProperties>
</ImageTexture >
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer a bit more?

Comment: In your code you need to replace `<ImageTexture url="texture.png"></ImageTexture>` with the code in the answer.

Comment: I did notice in the document, it states "Mipmaps are required for filtering modes with MIPMAP in their value", but I never feel like it has anything to do with linear filtering, so I look up [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_filtering#Linear_mipmap_filtering) and it surely says linear mipmap filtering, wow.